# How to quickly cut slices from cuda tensor wrt to another tensors values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

I have a torch cuda tensor `A` of shape `(100, 80000, 4)`, and another cuda tensor `B` of shape `(1, 80000, 1)`. What I want to do, is for each element `i` in the second dimension (from `0` to `79999`), take the value of tensor `B` (which will be from `0` to `99` and will point out to which value in the first dimension of `A` to take.

An additional problem is that for this element of `B` (`B[0, i, 0]`), I want to take a slice from `A` that is `A[lower_bound:upper_bound, i:i+1, :]`.

To sum it up, my tensor B has the indices of the centers of slices that I would like to cut from A. I am wondering, whether there is a way, to do what I am doing with the below code faster (eg. using cuda)

```
A  # tensor of shape (100, 80000, 4)
B  # tensor of shape (1, 80000, 1) which has 
k = 3  # width of the slice to take (or half of it to be exact)

A_list = []
for i in range(80000):
    lower_bound = max(0, B[0, i, 0]-k)
    upper_bound = min(100, B[0, i, 0]+k+1)
    A_mean = A[lower_bound:upper_bound, i:i+1, :].mean(0, keepdim=True)
    A_list.append(A_mean)

A = torch.cat(A_list , dim=1)
```

Comment: what is `k` in your code snipet?

Comment: `a[:, b.reshape(-1), :]` will give you `i`th element wanted.

Comment: k is the width of the slice that I want to take from A in the first dimension. In this case, 3. I  will update the code

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this can work if k = 1. (requires `torch>1.7`)

```
a = torch.rand((10, 20, 4))
b = torch.randint(10, (20, 1))
b2 = torch.cat((b-1, b, b+1), dim=1)
b2 = torch.minimum(9*torch.ones_like(b2), b2)
b2 = torch.maximum(0*torch.ones_like(b2), b2)
a[:, b2, :]
```

and then reshape to get the right size